# Android calendar with weekdays in horizontal

Tags: calendar

How I could get weekdays with horizontal scroll in recyclerview ?

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.widget_list);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getList());
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);   
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            if (isMultiSelect){
                //if multiple selection is enabled then select item on single click else perform normal click on item.
                multiSelect(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            if (!isMultiSelect){
                selectedIds = new ArrayList<>();
                isMultiSelect = true;

                if (actionMode == null){
                    actionMode = startActionMode(MainActivity.this); //show ActionMode.
                }
            }

            multiSelect(position);
        }
    }));
}
private void multiSelect(int position) {
    MyData data = adapter.getItem(position);
    if (data != null){
        if (actionMode != null) {
            if (selectedIds.contains(data.getId()))
                selectedIds.remove(Integer.valueOf(data.getId()));
            else
                selectedIds.add(data.getId());

            if (selectedIds.size() > 0)
                actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(selectedIds.size())); //show selected item count on action mode.
            else{
                actionMode.setTitle(""); //remove item count from action mode.
                actionMode.finish(); //hide action mode.
            }
            adapter.setSelectedIds(selectedIds);

        }
    }
}

/**
 * @see MyData Create dummy List of type MyData.
 * @return list
 */

String[] namesOfDays = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getShortWeekdays();
private List<MyData> getList(){
    List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyData(1,"Mon"));
    list.add(new MyData(2,"Tue"));
    list.add(new MyData(3,"Wed"));
    list.add(new MyData(4,"Thu"));
    list.add(new MyData(5,"Fri"));
    list.add(new MyData(6,"Sat"));
    list.add(new MyData(7,"Sun"));

    return list;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_select, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_delete:
            //just to show selected items.
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (MyData data : getList()) {
                if (selectedIds.contains(data.getId()))
                    stringBuilder.append("\n").append(data.getTitle());
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected items are :" + stringBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    actionMode = null;
    isMultiSelect = false;
    selectedIds = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter.setSelectedIds(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

Comment: go through this link to To write the Question Efficiently 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer

Comment: maybe this library help you 
https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Comment: no i need only week names